# ESC/POS different alignments in one line

Tags: delphi, escpos

I'm using Delphi, can somebody help me build correct ESC/POS command for to printout line like next:

```
"Article_Name        100.00$"
```

So the left part of line should have left alignment, and right part - right alignment. I'm trying to realise it with reverse feed:

```
'AAAAA' + Char($A);
'BBBBB' + Char($1B) + "K" + Char(30);
Char($1B)+'a'+Char(2) - set right alignment
'CCCCC' + Char($A);
Char($1B)+'a'+Char(1) - set back left alignment
```

so reverse feed is works, but alignment not( so in result printout i have:

```
AAAAA
BBBBBCCCCC
```

Can i realise it over ESC/POS commands or i have to build needed string over some format function?

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, ESC/POS 'alignment' is for all the data on the row, and will perhaps only work before you write anything to the line. So you can either:

- *try* and see wether a 'carriage return' (CR: `Char(13)` or `Char($D)`) only and then a different `Char($1B)+'a'+Char(...)` will work,
- or, assuming you use a monospaced font, use Delphi code to format the data in a fixed-length string. [Perhaps with the Format function.](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Format)

**Extra tip:** You can write `+Char()+` by using the `#` syntax, for example: `'BBBBB'#$1B'K'#30`

Comment: Thank's for your help. With 'carriage return' also no needed result. I will continue to search way for to realise it over ESC/POS because in my report can be different fonts and analyze all this things over format function it's to hard

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any way for to realise it over ESC/POS command. So this is my realisation of format function:

```
procedure TNativePrint.DoAddLineWithTwoAlignments(const ALeftStr : string;
                                              ALeftStrFont : TFontType;
                                              ALeftStrFontStyle : TFontStyle;
                                              const ARightStr : string;
                                              ARightStrFont : TFontType;
                                              ARightStrFontStyle : TFontStyle;
                                              APrintAreaWidth : integer = 500);
const
  vFomatLine = '';

var
  vOffset : integer;
  vCharSize : integer;
  vLeftSize : integer;
  vRightSize : integer;

begin
  vCharSize := 12;
  if (ALeftStrFont = ftFontA) then begin
    vCharSize := 12;
  end else if (ALeftStrFont = ftFontB) then begin
    vCharSize := 9;
  end;

  if (ALeftStrFontStyle in [fsDoubleWidth, fsDoubleHW, fsBoldDoubleWidth, fsBoldDoubleHW]) then begin
    vCharSize := vCharSize * 2;
  end;

  vLeftSize := length(ALeftStr) * vCharSize;

  if (ARightStrFont = ftFontA) then begin
    vCharSize := 12;
  end else if (ARightStrFont = ftFontB) then begin
    vCharSize := 9;
  end;

  if (ARightStrFontStyle in [fsDoubleWidth, fsDoubleHW, fsBoldDoubleWidth, fsBoldDoubleHW]) then begin
    vCharSize := vCharSize * 2;
  end;

  vRightSize := length(ARightStr) * vCharSize;

  vOffset := APrintAreaWidth - ( vLeftSize + vRightSize);

  DoSetFont(ALeftStrFont, ALeftStrFontStyle);
  DoAddLine(ALeftStr, false);

  DoSetFont(ARightStrFont, ARightStrFontStyle);
  DoAddLine(#$1B'\'+AnsiChar(vOffset)+#0, false);
  DoAddLine(ARightStr);
end;
```

As you can see i'm analysing font, font style and print area width, depend from it i calculate offset